K8S RBAC Role/Clusterrole naming validation for the apigroups, verbs, resources?
I noticed when creating a K8S role or clusterole there is NO naming validation for the apigroups, verbs nor resources. I mean I created a clusterrole and for the apiGroups field instead of rbac.authorization.k8s.io I typed rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1 (which is the apiversion from kubectl api-resources ) and I did not get any error when creating the clusterrole. Also instead of  resources: - secretproviderclasses I typed  resources:  - SecretProviderClasses (with some upper letters) and also I could not access this resource because of the incorrect naming. I would like to ask whether there is a place or a method to validate the syntax of the K8S RBAC roles/clusterroles? Thank you.

There is a kubectl-validate command line tool maintained by the K8s team.
You can find it here.
In anycase kubectl validate still gives an unknown command error, run this:
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin

Then try again:
kubectl validate path/to/manifest.yml -o json


To list all the resources in the cluster, you can type kubectl api-resources and then you can check the resource and the version that you can to use in your clusterrole.
